# second item of list is not showing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

this is my viewModel code:

```
    val workout = state.get<Workout>("workout")
    
    var steps : List<Step> = emptyList()

    fun  getSteps() = viewModelScope.launch {
        steps = workout?.let { stepDao.getWorkoutSteps(it.workoutId) }!!
        Log.e("KEK", steps.size.toString())
    }
```

and the fragment:

```
        viewModel.getSteps()

        if (viewModel.steps.isNotEmpty()) {
            binding.apply {
                currentStepName.text = viewModel.steps[0].name
                currentStepDuration.text = viewModel.steps[0].length.toString()
                nextStep.text = "${viewModel.steps[1].name} : ${viewModel.steps[1].length.toString()}"
            }
        }
```

this part where i fill the nextStep text doesn't work, a second item in the list exists, but the text doesn't get shown `

thank you

Comment: Make sure that the height parameter of your root layout in your recyclerview xml is set to "wrap-content".

Answer (score 1):

When you call `viewModel.getSteps()` it starts a coroutine, so you need to wait for it to finish. but you don't wait and try to update the UI using `viewModel.steps` which may not have been updated yet, because coroutine may not have started.

in your case you can use a `LiveData` object to fix the issue.

In your `ViewModel`

```
val liveSteps: MutableLiveData<List<Step>> = MutableLiveData()

fun  getSteps() = viewModelScope.launch {
        steps = workout?.let { stepDao.getWorkoutSteps(it.workoutId) }!!
        liveSteps.postValue(steps)
        Log.e("KEK", steps.size.toString())
    }
```

Now observe this `LiveData` in Fragment and update UI

```
viewModel.liveSteps.observe(viewLifeCycleOwner, androidx.lifecycle.observe{
    if(!(it.isNullOrEmpty()) && it.size == 2){
        binding.apply {
                currentStepName.text = it[0].name
                currentStepDuration.text = it[0].length.toString()
                nextStep.text = "${it[1].name} : ${it[1].length.toString()}"
            }
    }
})
```